# Manipulating API data in Python before appending to a csv file

Tags: python, rest, csv

I'm requesting data from a RESTful API. The first request is written to a csv file with no problems. In the csv file the data has 5 header rows (including column headers), 11 rows of actual data (13 fields per row), and an EOF row, so 17 rows of data in all (the data as it appears following a print(response.text) command is shown at the end of this post.

For subsequent requests to the API I simply want to append the 11 rows of data (i.e. rows 6 through 16) to the existing csv file. This is a process I will repeat numerous times in order to create a single large csv file with probably close to a million rows of data. I'm struggling to find a way to manipulate the data returned by the API so as to allow me to only write rows 6 through 16 to the csv file.

I'm pretty new to coding and Python, so I'd be grateful for suggestions as to how to proceed.

This is what the data looks like from a Python 'print' command (the first asterix is row 1. The fifth asterix denotes the start of the column headings, with 'Document RevNum' being the last column heading):

```
*
*
*Actual Aggregated Generation Per Type (B1620) Data
*
*Document Type,Business Type,Process Type,Time Series ID,Quantity,Curve Type,Resolution,Settlement Date,Settlement Period,Power System Resource  Type,Active Flag,Document ID,Document RevNum
Actual generation per type,Solar generation,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614701,3250,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Solar",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Wind generation,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614702,2075.338,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Wind Offshore",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Wind generation,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614703,1486.519,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Wind Onshore",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614704,258,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Other",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614705,4871,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Nuclear",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614706,0,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Fossil Oil",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614707,16448,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Fossil Gas",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614708,0,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Fossil Hard coal",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614709,783,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Hydro Run-of-river and poundage",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614710,118,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Hydro Pumped Storage",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
Actual generation per type,Production,Realised,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-TS-21614711,3029,Sequential fixed size block,PT30M,2020-07-01,21,"Biomass",Y,NGET-EMFIP-AGPT-06372506,1
<EOF>
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your problem as not being able to append the newly fetched data to the CSV file. I am not sure whether you are working with some module that helps with working with CSV files, but I just assume you don't for now.

If you just open the file with "a" as the second argument to open like (`f = open("file.csv","a")`) you can easily append the new content. You would first off have to strip the EOF row though and later append a new one, but I think that isn't the problem.
Hope I could help you, and please tell me whether I understood correctly what your problem is here :)

Btw, I would recommend looking into a CSV module for this or something like sqlite3.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, for my subsequent writes to the csv file I open the file as you suggest and it appends fine. You are correct that I want to strip out the EOF before appending, but i also want to strip out the first five rows starting with *, and only append rows 6-16 - this is what I'm struggling to do. Thanks for any suggestions you can offer.

Comment: In which format do you get the data from the API?
If it is a list you can just split it like so `api_resp[6:-1]` to get everything but the first 5 lines and the EOF.

Comment: Newbie question - how do I know if the api response is a list? In the variables explorer the data values are visible under the 'text' name, with type 'str' - is that a list? Certainly when I write it to the csv it presents in the file as a two dimensional table of 11 rows and 13 columns, preceeded by 5 rows of header info and followed by the EOF row. Do I have to assign the api_resp[5:-1] to an object? ie responseRows = api_resp[5:-1]?  Thanks

Comment: PS: if I try the split as suggested I get TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: I think you are using the `requests` module for making the API call and that indeed returns a "Response" object (that's also what the Error tells you)
If you print the .text attribute of the Response, does it have newlines splitting the rows?
If so you can just do `csv_data = resp.split("\n")` and then you have a list. (You can check the type with `print(type(csv_data))`.

Comment: There is no \n demarking the end of a row. Even so, the print(response.text) command still produces a pretty neat output (see copy/paste above) with each row starting on a new line.

Comment: I seem to be making some progress. I followed your suggestion and ended up with the following code:

data = response.text
print(data)
data1=data.split(",1")
print(data1)
print(data1[6:-1])

The split divided the response.text using the last field value of ",1", which seems to be present in every row. 

when I then print data1 it shows me the same data s before except there is now a \n at the end of every row.

the print(data1[6:-1) prints only rows 6-16, suggesting perhaps that I may be able to append the same to the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which seems to work is as follows:

Recall that the API returns a long string of comma-separated data for a given date.
When the data is written to a csv file it presents as 4 rows of 'header' data that I'm not interested in, 1 row of column heading data (13 columns), 11 rows of the data that I AM interested in (with data in all 13 columns), and 1 ("EOF") row that I don't need.

On the first API query I want to create a csv file with only the column headings and 11 rows of data, jettisoning the first 4 rows (redundant info) and the last row ("EOF") of data.

On all subsequent API queries I simply want to append the 11 rows of data to the already created csv file.

The API response is returned as a string.

The following code excludes the first 4 rows and the last row ("EOF") but still writes the column headings and the 11 rows of useful data to the newly created csv file:

```
# Write to .CSV
with open('C:/Users/Paul/.spyder-py3/Elexon API Data 05.csv', "w") as f:
    f.write(api_response.text[59:-5])
```

The first 59 characters and last 5 characters of the API response string will always be the same so I can be confident that this will work for the initial API response.

For subsequent API responses I use the following code to append to the csv file:

```
# Now append the api response data to the CSV file
with open('C:/Users/Paul/.spyder-py3/Elexon API Data 05.csv', "a") as f:
    f.write(api_response.text[248:-5])
```

This excludes the first 248 and last 5 characters from the API response appended to the csv file. The first 248 characters of the string will always include the same redundant info, and the last 5 characters will always include the '', so again I can be confident that only the 11 rows of data I am interested in will be appended to the csv file.

The solution, for this particular case, turned out to be simpler than I had expected, and thanks to [CodingGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13820835/codingguy) for directing me to think in terms of stripping data from the start and end of the api response, and for exploring the type of data I was dealing with.

Please let me know if there are problems with my solution. Likewise, I'm always interested to learn more sophisticated ways of handling data within Python.